# Question on Oracle OEM version and plugin version upgrade

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-enterprise-manager, plugins

I have a OEM 12c (12.1.0.4) running in my setup in which I have registered over 70-80 databases. I see the plugin updates with versions of each target (Oracle database, MS-SQL, MySQL) and I have the downloaded the plugin updates as well.

1. My question is that can I update my plugin which is higher version than my OEM itself?
2. If yes, should I update my plugin one version at a time? Say, my deployed oracle database plugin version is 12.1.0.4 and available downloaded versions for the same I have is 12.1.0.6 and 12.1.0.7. So I should update the 6 release first and then the 7? Also how to go ahead with the update?
3. Are there upgrades for the OEM itself? from 12.1.0.4 to a higher version? If yes, how to go ahead with it? Are there any MOS if you could share?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Plugins are deployed on the OMS and the agents as well. First you should upgrade the plugin on the OMS, then on the agents.
2. You don't need to upgrade between versions sequentially, you can upgrade to the highest available.
3. Yes, there are. Currently 12.1.0.5 is the latest version, and there are quarterly PSUs as well. Check the below MOS note:

**Oracle Recommended Patches (PSU) for Enterprise Manager Base Platform (All Releases) (Doc ID 822485.1)**

There is no PSU released for 12.1.0.5 yet.

Comment: 1. Plugin upgrade if done on OMS, will it automatically upgrade the agents deployed in agents as well? Or I should manually upgrade each and every agent in each host?                                                                                                 2. While updating Oracle database agent plugin, it says downtime is required. But how much downtime, how can I find? Will it affect all my hosts or only the OEM host.?

Comment: @tesla747 1. It will not upgrade them automatically, you will have to do that later. But you can select multiple agents and deploy the new plugin on all of them at once. 2. The downtime affects only Enterprise Manager, not the monitored targets. Usually it takes 15-30 minutes, and you can monitor its progress on the OEM host  using `emctl status oms -details`.

Comment: mate, DOC 1900943.1 shows hell a lot of patch sets specified for each. I should go about applying each patch set separately or what?

Comment: Latest is Oracle EM 13c, I believe